# Copy hangs in local network

Tags: networking, nautilus, files

I want to copy files from one Ubuntu system to another.They are both in local wireless network.

I shared entire home dir on one, and tried to copy some files to another. It works for some time and then it just hangs at some point.

I use Nautilus to copy files.

Here is the example screenshot, it just hangs like this:

[image]

After I cancel, Nautilus icon in lauchbar keeps progress bar, so I guess there is some problem.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using [Krusader](http://www.krusader.org/).

As time goes I'm more and more disappointed with Nautilus. It's slow and [buggy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1075516).